# Using shell to finds directories that do not have a specified pattern of files in the folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

The directory tree is like this:

```
.
├── A_123
│   └── 123.txt
├── A_456
│   ├── tmp
│   └── tmp.log
└── A_789
    └── 789.txt
```

There're 3 directories (A_123, A_456, A_789). 
The pattern of a directory name is: `A_{numbers}` and the file I'm interested in is `{numbers}.txt`.

I was wondering whether there's a way to get the directories `A_{numbers}` that has no `{numbers}.txt` file in them. For example above, this script should return:

```
./A_456
```

as `A_456` doesn't have `456.txt` in its folder but `A_123` and `A_789` have their `{numbers}.txt` files in the relevant folder.

Anyone has ideas about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
for dir in *;do 
  if [ $(find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -regex '.*/[0-9][0-9]*\.txt' | wc -l) = 0 ]; then 
    echo $dir
  fi
done
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this. `*` will also match files. The regex will match a file named ".txt". Using an ERE regextype, you can say `[0-9]+`. There are some similar matching issues in my answer though. The `-regex` option for find is not POSIX, but should be fine since the question is tagged linux.

Comment: If for some reason, `A_123` directory contains `000.txt` (but not `123.txt`), the directory won't be echoed. Although from OP's sample, it seems that the text file's name always matches the folder's number (if it exists) so this might not be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Since the A_[0-9] directories are not nested, you can easily do this with a glob in a loop. This implementation is pure bash, and does not spawn in external utilities:

```
for d in A_[0-9]*/; do         # the trailing / causes only directories to be matched
   files=("$d"/[0-9]*.txt)     # populate an array with matching text files
   ((!${#files})) && echo "$d" # echo $d if the array is empty
done
```

There are some problems with this implementation. It will match a file such as "12ab.txt" and requires loading all the filenames for a directory into the array.

Here is another method in bash that does a more accurate filename matching:

```
re='^[0-9]+[.]txt$'
for d in A_[0-9]*/; do
   for f in *; do
      if [[ -f $f && $f =~ $re ]]; then
         echo "$d"
         break
      fi
   done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on a couple of other answers: use bash [extended pattern matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for dir in  A_+([0-9]); do
    files=($dir/+([0-9]).txt)
    (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )) && echo $dir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *; do
  if [[ "$file" =~ ^A_([0-9]+)$ && ! -f "$file/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt" ]]; then
    echo $file;
  fi
done
```

How it works:

1. Checks using regexp (note the `=~` ) that the file/folder's name is "A_" followed by number.
2. At the same time, it captures the numbers (note the parentheses) and stores them in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`
3. Next, check if the folder contains `{number}.txt`.
4. If it does not, echo the folder's name.